# Find all paths under a specific weight in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory

Does anyone have any idea about how to find all paths from a source vertex to a target vertex under a specific weight in a graph?

PS, the graph is huge in my case (around million vertices), but a general efficient algorithm  would also be appreciated.

Please don't say to run Yen's algorithm with some search for the "correct" k.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not implement a Dijkstra algorithm with a weight condition on each node, and stop the traversal from the current node if your "specific" weight is exceeded ? So the algorithm may run until the end vertex is reached, and try to find another path if the weigth on the current node is big enough

Comment: You have to be more specific about your question. What do you mean by all paths? All paths starting at a particular node and ending at another specified node, or paths between every pair of node in your graph? And how big is your graph? Billions of edges?

Comment: Marcassin - could you please explain your suggestion?
lightalchemist - thanks.

Comment: Dijkstra is a common algorithm to find the shortest path in a connex graph. New weigth is calculated on each vertex using the weight calculated by the path leading to this current node. The weigth of a vertex is modified if another path have a lower cost to get to this node. You can stop the calculation of the current path if the cost with the next node is upper than your specific weight : the algo gonna step back, and continue the calculation with another path. Get a look to dijkstra pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

There is an [answer on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/18634) for finding all paths in an undirected graph. You can modify this answer to include weight consideration. As he stated in his answer

> The idea is very simple: Do an exhaustive search, but bail early if you've gotten yourself into a corner.

In addition to that, you will have to bail when the weight is off the limit.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the problem is that the paths aren't gathered in an ordered way, and thus I can't just stop when some path's weight is off limit. And if you meant that I should "collect" them with a weight order, it's the core of my question.